# BigQuery export with TIMESTAMP of derived tables broken?

Tags: google-bigquery

I noticed that export to storage from a BigQuery derived table (table constructed from a query of another table) does strip the TIMESTAMP from the result.

1. Table table with **TIMESTAMP**
2. Do a query on that table, example "SELECT user_id,subscription_date FROM [All.Users] LIMIT 1000" (reproduced it with one row, two columns)
   3.In Query options: Export **query result to table**: example "temp.Reproduce". I used allow large result to make sure to use the same option as in production.
3. **Export** that new table "temp.Reproduce" to AVRO or CSV. (example: gs://bucket/temp/part*.avro)
4. Notice that the TIMESTAMP **value is missing**!

Is someone else noticing the same?

Comment: Note: Export on a table that has imported from storage works (or at least that was imported a while ago) does export correctly.

Comment: This was reported here: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=255

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Mosha, to pointing it out in the issues list:

[Export to GCS in CSV format renders datetime field as empty](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=255)

The issue is resolved in the meantime.